# proving a property of weak convergence in $L^1(E)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E\subseteq\Bbb R$ be a set of finite measure. Assume the sequence ${f_{n}}$ is in $L^1(E)$ and $f_{n}\to f$ weakly in $L^1(E)$. Show that if $f_{n}\geq  M$ almost everywhere for a constant $M$ then $f\geq M$ almost everywhere.

I tried providing it by contradiction, supposing $f<m$ on a subset of $E$ with positive measure. Then of course for every $n\in\Bbb N$, there is a subset $A_{n}$ of $A$ such that $f_{n}\geq M$ on $A_{n}$, but I can't go any further.

Comment: $f_n\ge M$ on all of $A$, in fact. Note the indicator function on $A$ is a bounded linear functional.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F=\{x\in E: f(x)<M\}$. Then $\int_Ff_n \to \int_F f$ because $\chi_F \in L^{\infty}$. Hence  $\int_F f \geq M \mu (F)$. Can you finish?